# Python: Extract Key, Value Pairs From A Dictionary - Key Contains Specific Text

Tags: python, search, dictionary, count

I currently have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{OctetString('Ethernet8/6'): Integer(1),
 OctetString('Ethernet8/7'): Integer(2),
 OctetString('Ethernet8/8'): Integer(2),
 OctetString('Ethernet8/9'): Integer(1),
 OctetString('Vlan1'): Integer(2),
 OctetString('Vlan10'): Integer(1),
 OctetString('Vlan15'): Integer(1),
 OctetString('loopback0'): Integer(1),
 OctetString('mgmt0'): Integer(1),
 OctetString('port-channel1'): Integer(1),
 OctetString('port-channel10'): Integer(1),
 OctetString('port-channel101'): Integer(1),
 OctetString('port-channel102'): Integer(1)}
```

I want my dictionary to look like this:

```
{OctetString('Ethernet8/6'): Integer(1),
 OctetString('Ethernet8/7'): Integer(2),
 OctetString('Ethernet8/8'): Integer(2),
 OctetString('Ethernet8/9'): Integer(1)}
```

I am not sure what is the best way to find these key, value pairs. I really want anything that matches '\Ethernet(\d*)/(\d*)'. However I am not sure the best way to go about this. My main goal is to match all the Ethernet Values and then count them. For example: After I have the dict matching all of Ethernetx/x I want to count the amount of 1's and 2's.

Also, why do I get only Ethernet8/6 when I iterate the dictionary and print, but when I pprint the dictionary I end up with OctetString('Ethernet8/6')?

```
for k in snmp_comb: print k
Ethernet2/18
Ethernet2/31
Ethernet2/30
Ethernet2/32
Ethernet8/46
```

Comment: you are almost done, Create a `regex` for `'\Ethernet(\d*)/(\d*)'` and check it for every key in the given dictionary.

Comment: Hey @anmol_uppal, I am still very new to Python, how would I do that exactly? I have searched re in python but am having trouble when trying to get that to work, re doesn't like it when I iterate through a dictionary. I think it expects a string.

Comment: There are a lot of methods in the `re` module, The best suited for your case is `re.match(expression, string)`, where `expression = 'Ethernet(\d*)/(\d*)'` and string is the word you want to test upon. returns None if the word doesn't matches the expression.

Comment: what is `OctetString('Ethernet8/6')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
new_dict = dict()
for key, value in orig_dict.items():
    if 'Ethernet' in str(key):
        new_dict[key] = value
```

When you use `print`, python calls the `__str__` method on the `OctetString` object, which returns `Ethernet8/6`. However, I *think* `pprint` defaults to printing the object type.

**EDIT:**

Stefan Pochmann has rightly pointed out below that `if 'Ethernet' in` will match any string which contains the word `Ethernet`. The OP did mention using regex in his post to match `Ethernet(\d*)/(\d*)`, so this answer may not be suitable to anyone else looking to solve a similar problem.

Comment: An explanation of the downvote would be helpful and not just to me!

Comment: It is always so much easier than I make it out to be... Thanks.

Comment: I often have the same problem @Matt! Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: @Erve1879 Wasn't me who downvoted, but I imagine it's because you might match more than you should (e.g., "MyEthernet") or because you're making it harder than it needs to be.

Comment: new_dict={k:v for k,v in orig_dict.items() if 'Ethernet' in k}

Comment: @StefanPochmann - good point on matching more than the OP might want. I shall add an edit. But "harder" is the next man's "easier", especially without an example of how you think it could be easier. Ajay has commented with a one-line version of my answer which works in fewer lines and could therefore be considered better, but I would argue is harder for a n00b to read (not saying the OP is a n00b). But thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @Erve1879 Yeah, the comprehension is one shorter solution and I think with nice formatting, it's very easy to read. But mostly I though of the OP's "I want my dictionary to look like this", so I think deleting the unwanted entries from the dictionary is both more correct and easier. I posted it in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @StefanPochmann - I see what you mean. A subtle, yet important distinction.

Comment: Can you do the same thing for values as an int?

Comment: @Matt - yes, but you might need to either remove the `str()`, or replace it with `int()`, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

(I'll use the same `'Ethernet' in str(key)` test as the accepted answer.)

If you want to keep the original dict and have the filtered version as a separate dictionary, I'd use a comprehension:

```
newdict = {key: value
           for key, value in mydict.items()
           if 'Ethernet' in str(key)}
```

If you don't want to keep the original dict, you can also just remove the entries you don't want:

```
for key in list(mydict):
    if 'Ethernet' in str(key):
        del mydict[key]
```

The reason you get "OctetString('...')" is the same as this one:

```
>>> 'foo'
'foo'
>>> pprint.pprint('foo')
'foo'
>>> print('foo')
foo
```

The first two tests show you a representation you can use in source code, that's why there are quotes. It's what the `repr` function gets you. The third test prints the value for normal pleasure, so doesn't add quotes. The "OctetString('...')" is simply such a representation as well, and you can copy&paste it into source code and get actual OctetString objects again, rather than Python string objects. I guess `pprint` is mostly intended for developing, where it's more useful to get the full `repr` version.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I am using pysnmp to get the value and I'm converting it into dict. I guess the OctetString is how pysnmp interpreted the data. Makes sense.